# Check if finger is over actor - libgdx

Tags: java, android, button, libgdx, touch

I'm trying with this but I don't know how can I get the boolean from here.

```
    button.addListener(new InputListener() {
        public boolean touchdown;
        @Override
        public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                            int pointer, Actor fromActor) {

            touchdown=true;
        }

        @Override
        public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                          int pointer, Actor toActor) {
            touchdown=false;
        }
    });
```

What I want is check if my finger is over a button, not just if I press it. For example if I'm already with the finger in the screen and put it on the button I need it to detect it.
Also, I'm new with Java and I want to ask about what's the difference about make a boolean public or private. Also, if I don't declare it like public/private, what happens? I've been searching but I don't find anything related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
                  // write your code
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```